# HAProxy - What happens to executing requests when server goes into maintenance mode?

Tags: haproxy

I have HAProxy set with cookie persistence. When I am setting a server to maintenance mode, what happens with currently executing requests on it? does HAProxy kill them or does it let them complete? I know new requests (even with the cookie pointing to the down server) will be redirected to other servers but I tried reading through the HAProxy documentation but could not find any information on what happens with executing requests.

Answer (score 0):

The MAINT mode is like a hard stop, it kills connections. The DRAIN mode will allow any existing connections AND any new connections with valid persistence templates (until the stick table timeout). New connections with no persistence template will be redirected.

Interestingly DOWN mode from a health check WILL allow connections to continue unless you add the option: on-marked-down shutdown-sessions.

I'm 99% confident in my answer - But always best to run some tests yourself to double check :-).

Comment: So if I am using cookie persistence without any stick table persistence then the clients will go to my down machine forever (until they close their browser). Based on your answer I guess if I set the server to down then all incoming new requests will be redirected (even if a cookie says to use the down server) while executing requests will still finish first

Comment: Yes, But You can use maxidle to adjust the cookie timeout:

cookie MyCookieName maxidle 30m maxlife 12h insert nocache indirect